# Removing top arrow when view on smaller screen

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

In my bootstrap theme I have added an up arrow to the dropdown menu

[image]

using the following css

```
.dropdown-menu:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  right: 9px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 7px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 7px solid #ccc;
  border-left: 7px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  content: '';
 }

.dropdown-menu:after {
 position: absolute;
 top: -6px;
 right: 10px;
 display: inline-block;
 border-right: 6px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 6px solid #ffffff;
 border-left: 6px solid transparent;
 content: '';
}
```

The problem is that when I shrink the browser window to check how it would look like in mobile devices, I see the arrow still there which does not look good. How Can I make the arrow responsive so that it does not show up on smaller displays.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this with a [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries). There may already be one more or less set up for you in the bootstrap css file. You can either a) override the style you have when your browser's viewport goes below a certain width (with `display: none;` or similar), or b) make it so the arrow only shows up when your browser viewport is above a certain width. I think the latter is the better way to go. To add a media query, wrap your style rules like this:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .dropdown-menu:after {
        position: absolute;
        [...]
    }
}
```

You may need to tweak the width, but the idea is that rule will only be applied when the viewport width is, at a minimum, 768px.